# Flask - Can't access static files for root address

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, static-files, blueprint

I'm working on creating a personal test-website for myself using Flask, however I discovered a behaviour I can not full get behind and could need some help with.

I have separated my website into indivudial chunks using Flask's blueprint system, because it makes sense for my case (since I want it to contain multiple smaller test-applications). I am suspecting that my problem is rooted in my project stucture, so I am giving a brief overview over what I did. Here is my (simplified) project setup:

```
>File structure:
root (contains some linux start scripts)
  - run.py
  - website (the actual flask project folder)
      - __init__.py (registers blueprints)
      - blueprints
          - __init__.py (empty)
          - website
              - __init__.py (defines routes, creates blueprint)
              - static (static files for this blueprint)
                  - css
                      - example.css
              - templates (render templates for this blueprint)
                  - example.html.j2
          - app1
              - <Same structure as above>
          - app2
              - <Same structure as above>
          - ...

>run.py
from website import createApp
createApp().run(debug=True)


>website/__init__.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template

def createApp():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.testing = True

    # Website
    from blueprints.website import website
    app.register_blueprint(website())
    # App1
    from blueprints.app1 import app1
    app.register_blueprint(app1())
    # App2
    from blueprints.app2 import app2
    app.register_blueprint(app2())
    ...
    return app


>website/blueprints/website/__init__.py:
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
bp = Blueprint("website", __name__, url_prefix="/", 
template_folder="templates", static_folder="static")
def website():
    return bp

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('example.html.j2')


>website/blueprints/website/templates/example.html.j2
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet", href="{{url_for('website.static', filename='css/example.css')}}">
    <title>Test Page!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test page!
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected result: The page should appear with the style defined in **example.css** 
Actual result: Loading the **example.css** document results in a 404 error.

Since I've tried to deal with this for a few hours now I think I have nailed the problem down to Flask being weird when it comes to the root address.

Since the blueprint defines the address as `url_prefix="/"` I access it by typing "website.com" into my browser. (The browser tries to call the resource over "website.com/static/css/example.css", but get a 404 response.)

If I change the address to something like `url_prefix="/test"` and access the page via "website.com/test", the stylesheet will be loaded successfully. (The browser now tries to call the resource over "website.com/test/static/css/example.css", this time the document is found and loaded.)

Since this is supposed to be the main page I do want for it to use the root address though.

I would be grateful for someone to shine some light onto this and explain to me where my error lays.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. The only thing I can think off is that you might have specified that `website.com/static` holds all your static files in your WSGI server script. Therefore, the flask app doesn't interfere which requests to `website.com/static` and these requests are handled by the WSGI server which can't find them in the folder.

Does this problem also occur when using the development server?

Can you try changing the static server in your WSGI setup to the `website/blueprints/static/website` folder?

And finally if this doesn't help, can you make a small github repo with this problem? Its pretty hard to reproduce this problem with these kinds of imports and filetrees.

Comment: The environment is already the Flask developement server which is running on the Linux server of a friend. I have never looked into WSGI, it will take me a bit to test that out since I need to experiment a little, I'll get back with the results of that.